# Flink Broadcast non-KeyedStream to a KeyedStream

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two streams, stream1 and stream2. Streams are coming from Kafka Topics. Stream1 is a KeyedStream which contains the main data that I want to process in keyed-context. Stream2 is simply a "trigger" stream. What I mean is that Stream1 will print the results it has generated so far only when a trigger arrives from stream2. My problem is that I cant find a way to broadcast the trigger event of stream2 to all partitions of stream1, so they all start printing the results.
Any ideas on how to do this?
Note: I dont want to use Windows.

Moreover, in flink documentation I see an operator "broadcast" : Datastream -> DataStream but I haven't found any examples to understand how this is used. Can someone explain?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [The Broadcast State Pattern](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/) page, which has an example of doing something similar to your use case. To summarize...

- When a `stream1` element is received by `processElement()`, you save it in (keyed) state.
- When a stream2 (control) element is received by `processBroadcastElement`, you get use the `ctx.applyToKeyedState(StateDescriptor<S, VS> stateDescriptor, KeyedStateFunction<KS, S> function)` method to access/emit all of the records you've saved in state for `stream1`.

Comment: I've checked it. Broadcast state will not work for the following reason: When trigger arrives, the processBroadcastElemet will set the state as "triggered" so the processElement function (responsible for stream1) knows that "it's time to start printing the result its computed so far". But the broadcast state will remain "triggered" and all subsequent events of stream1 will be printed too. In other words, one trigger of stream2 will indeed activate the printing but there's no way to deactivate it as the processElement function has read only access to the broadcast state, so it can't change it

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more explicit. See `.applyToKeyedState()`.